# ¿Como rotar una imagen BMP en c?

Tags: c

Estoy estancado en este problema desde hace ya un par de días, y la mayoria de la información que encuentro esta para otros lenguajes y bueno...Estoy intentando rotar una imagen BMP 90 grados. Me he quedado estancado en este método.

```
void rotarI(BMP* img,char* nom){

BMP** new;
int* newrows;
int* newcols;

FILE *archivo; //Puntero de tipo FILE para abrir el archivo de imagen

    archivo = fopen(nom,"rb+"); //abre la imagen a partir de la ruta, rb+ quiere decir que se va a leer el archivo
    if(!archivo){ //si no se encuentra la imagen en la ruta dada
        printf("No se encontro la imagen %s",nom);
        exit(0);
    }

//Lee la cabecera de la imagen y almacena en la estructura a la que apunta la imagen
fseek(archivo,0, SEEK_SET);
fread(&img->bm,sizeof(char),2, archivo);
fread(&img->tamano,sizeof(int),1, archivo);
fread(&img->reservado,sizeof(int),1, archivo);  
fread(&img->offset,sizeof(int),1, archivo); 
fread(&img->tamanoMetadatos,sizeof(int),1, archivo);    
fread(&img->alto,sizeof(int),1, archivo);   
fread(&img->ancho,sizeof(int),1, archivo);  
fread(&img->numPlanos,sizeof(short int),1, archivo);    
fread(&img->profColor,sizeof(short int),1, archivo);    
fread(&img->tipoCompresion,sizeof(int),1, archivo);
fread(&img->tamEstruc,sizeof(int),1, archivo);
fread(&img->pxmh,sizeof(int),1, archivo);
fread(&img->pxmv,sizeof(int),1, archivo);
fread(&img->colorUsa,sizeof(int),1, archivo);
fread(&img->colorImp,sizeof(int),1, archivo);   

//Se reserva memoria
*new = (BMP*)malloc(img->alto*img->ancho*sizeof(BMP)); 
int c,r;//counters for rows and columns
*newrows = img->ancho;
*newcols = img->alto;
BMP *o;
BMP *n;
    for(r = 0; r < img->alto; r++)
    {
            for(c = 0; c < img->ancho; c++ )
            {
                    n = (*new) + (c * img->alto) + (img->alto + r + 1 );
                    o = ((img) + (r * img->ancho) + c);
                    *n = *o;
            }//end of for
    }//end of for
fclose(archivo);
}
```

No soy muy bueno en c así que indagando en internet encontre algunos fragmentos de código los cuales estoy usando como guía

El fragmento de codigo que estoy tratando de modificar es este:

```
int rotate(PIXEL* original, int rows, int cols, int rotation,
       PIXEL** new, int* newrows, int* newcols)
{
int c,r;//counters for rows and columns
*newrows = cols;
*newcols = rows;
//allocating space for the new rotated image
*new = (PIXEL*)malloc(rows*cols*sizeof(PIXEL));
PIXEL *o;
PIXEL *n;

    for(r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
            for(c = 0; c < cols; c++ )
            {
                    n = (*new) + (c * rows) + (rows + r + 1 );
                    o = ((original) + (r * cols) + c);
                    *n = *o;
            }//end of for
    }//end of for 
return 0;
}
```

Me gustaría que me echaran la mano y me guiaran.

Comment: Te recomiendo usar OpenCV. Es una libreria para procesamiento de imágenes. Te permite hacer ese timpo de transformaciones y más.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, como era un trabajo de la uni tenía que hacerlo todo en código sin usar librerías, el chiste era entender el comportamiento de las imágenes BMP.